# Using conditionals in express/handlebars

Tags: express, handlebars.js

I am using express and handlebars...kind of a newbie.  Looking to do something like pseudo code below using handlebars or by passing the array to the html page and processing it there...

```
var pagename = arrayofpages[0].pagename;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayofpages.length; i++) {
  if(!arrayofpages[i].pagename === pagename) {
    <h1>{{pagename}}</h1>
    pagename = arrayofpages[i].pagename;
  }else {
    <ul>...</ul>
  }  
}
```

Guessing from looking around Stackoverflow, nothing like that can be done with Handlebars, though a custom helper almost looked like it would work, but a regular #each block simply checks for falsie value...the second option would be ok too...

Option #2:  Simply passing the arrayofpages array to the page as an array and dealing with it there...can't seem to get that to work either. Something like the following pseudo code at the bottom of the template:

```
<script>
  var myArray = {{ arrayofpages }};
  console.log(arrayofpages);
</script>
```

I have tried JSON.stringify in the template and JSON.serialize on the client and a bunch of other alternatives and they all come back with 'unexpected tokens' (commas and/or html entities like "&#x27"; in the console...

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: OK...got the second option working...just needed {{{ arrayofpages }}} instead of the double braces...

Comment: ...so I guess I'll just loop through the array and add the appropriate elements to the dom on the client...though it seems like it should be able to be done in the template engine...maybe with a custom helper?  But this will work for now.